# SQL statement to find if dates is between two dates

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, date, where-clause

With a SQL statement, I want to find the entries for a single day.

**Consider the following entries:**

- Id 1, StartAt 2020-04-12 08:00:00.0000000, EndAt 2020-04-12 15:00:00.0000000
- Id 2, StartAt 2020-04-11 08:00:00.0000000, EndAt 2020-04-13 15:00:00.0000000

**When I want to find the entries for the day:**

- 2020-04-11, result should be: Id 2
- 2020-04-12, result should be: Id 1 and 2
- 2020-04-13, result should be: Id 2

I tried using different '<' '>' operators and the BETWEEN keyword, but couldn't get the right syntax, as it's a timeperiode I want to find, within another timeperiode.

Comment: Please tag your question with the database that you are using: sql-server,  mysql, oracle...? Date functions are highly vendor-specific.

Comment: Sure, I added the mssql database tag

Comment: I think your first result is wrong; it should be "2" not "1".

Comment: Your right, changed that in the example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want:

```
where @date <= endAt and
      dateadd(day, 1, @date) > startat
```

This returns any timespan that includes any time on the `@date`.

Answer (score 2):

Consider:

```
select count(*)
from mytable
where 
    @mydate >= cast(startAt as date) 
    and @mydate < dateadd(day, 1, cast(endAt as date))
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=b6e179f7d5d662a800905129bfafc476)** - you can play around with the value of `@mydate` to test the 3 scenarios.